# Loop for importing and calculating stock returns from multiple csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Maybe a stupid question, but I'm a beginner. I use below code to calculate stock returns and squared log returns:

```
#read csv
stock1 = pd.read_csv('http://mydata.com/q/c/?d=stock1%d1=20190101&d2=20200101')
stock2 = pd.read_csv('http://mydata.com/q/c/?d=stock2%d1=20190101&d2=20200101')

#calculate return
stock1['r'] = np.log(stock1.close) - np.log(stock1.close.shift(1))
stock2['r'] = np.log(stock2.close) - np.log(stock2.close.shift(1))

#calculate squared returns and rolling returns
stock1_sq_r = stock1['r'] * stock1['r']
stock2_sq_r = stock2['r'] * stock2['r']

rolled_s1_sq_r = stock1_sq_r.rolling(window=5).sum()
rolled_s2_sq_r = stock2_sq_r.rolling(window=5).sum()
```

It works as charm, but I need to do it for 100 stocks... How can I put above in loop?

I guess that the loop to read csv should be similar to this:

```
stocks = {'stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3'}
      for stock in stocks:
      url = ('http://http://mydata.com/q/c/?d={}%d1=20190101&d2=20200101')
      dfs = pd.read_csv(url.format(stock))
```

but it only reads data for stock3 and I have no idea how to loop the rest of calculation.

Thanks for any suggestions, directions, clues.

Comment: standard rule: `"if you have many elements then use list or dictionary"`. You assign always to the same variable `dfs` so you remove previous content. You have to add to list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read all values to a dictionary (`stock_name` as key and `dataframe` as value)

```
all_data_dict ={}

stocks = {'stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3'}
for stock in stocks:
   url = 'http://http://mydata.com/q/c/?d={}%d1=20190101&d2=20200101'.format(stock)
   all_data_dict[stock] = pd.read_csv(url)
```

you can access the the dataframe for 'stock1' fro the dictionary by

```
df = all_data_dict['stock1']
```

you can also use [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to find the difference with next value & use `**` to get the square

```
rolled_s1_sq_r = (np.log(df.close).diff()**2).rolling(window=5).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation could be your problem here. Try this:

```
stocks = {'stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3'}
      for stock in stocks:
          url = ('http://http://mydata.com/q/c/?d={}%d1=20190101&d2=20200101')
          dfs = pd.read_csv(url.format(stock))
```

Notice the indent inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will work better:

```
stocks = ['stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3']
for stock in stocks:
   url = f'http://mydata.com/q/c/?d={stock}%d1=20190101&d2=20200101'
   dfs = pd.read_csv(url)
```